# Content analysis isn’t nearly as scary as it sounds - the maning of nearly

Tags: grammar

> You can create perfectly written XML, but if your perfect XML doesn’t fit your content, all that work isn’t going to do diddly for you. This chapter is devoted to helping you get a handle on the content that you’re creating so you can use XML to describe it well. Content analysis isn’t **nearly as scary as it sounds**; a little analysis early on (tell us what you see in these ink blots) can save you from going loco later.

Okay. Let's first get rid of the word **nearly**. So, what we have reads: **Content analysis isn’t as scary as it sounds**. To me, that means that content analysis is not scary as it may sound to someone who first hears about it. Meaning, it's not scary. Fine. That's something I understand. But throwing the word **nearly** into the mix, how does it then alter the meaning of the sentence? Does it mean that content analysis is not scary at all? I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Longman dictionary, "not nearly" means "not at all".
So, the sentence means: Content analysis is not at all as scary as it sounds.
(Indeed it's scare, but not that much)